# How do I check whether InputField.Text contains two randomly generated letters?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, card

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LetterRandomiser : MonoBehaviour
{
    public char[] characters; 

    public Text textbox; 

    public InputField mainInputField;

    void Start() /*when the game starts*/
    {
        char c = characters[Random.Range(0,characters.Length)];
        textbox.text = c.ToString(); 
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.KeypadEnter) && mainInputField.text.Contains(textbox.text) == true)
        {
            char c = characters[Random.Range(0, characters.Length)];
            textbox.text = c.ToString();
            mainInputField.text = "";
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.KeypadEnter) && mainInputField.text.Contains(textbox.text) == false)
        {
            mainInputField.text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Reference to [my game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev2W8.png)

I'm trying to program my game so that the two textboxes (firstChar and secondChar) would choose one randomly generated letter each.

Then when a player types in a word in the input box, the game would check if the word contains the two randomly generated.

If it does, then the program would randomise the two textboxes again and the input field would be blank.

Otherwise the program wouldn't randomise those two textboxes and the player will have to try again.

However the program doesn't work. There are no errors but when I press enter, nothing happens, like shown on the image.

Comment: You are checking for KeypadEnter. The normal / big Enter ist Return:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.KeypadEnter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by @DerDingens.

> You are checking for KeypadEnter. The normal / big Enter ist Return:
> docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.KeypadEnter.html.